# WoW TCG Magtheridon Raid Strategies

Tags: wow-tcg

I'm going to be running Magtheridon for some friends and was looking for advice in general and wondering specifically about bloods. Should I try to keep them around, or spend them on various effects?

We will be running the raid allowing only cards that had been released at the time.

Comment: Man, I would love to answer this but Magtheridon is one I haven't played personally. Nice to see a `wow-tcg` question, though.

Comment: Closing as too broad, since this is a [strategy tips for X](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/86/5573) question.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you phrase the question makes me think that you misinterpreted the rules for how Blood works. Blood is not spent by cards like "Brush Aside". The "for every-" means that you just count the amount of blood. Blood is resource and you need to make sure that if you need them, you have them. Constantly using "Power Returns" will make it hard for you to use other abilities effectively, but it's a nice card to have when you are running low on options.